# Funções Nativas - Máximo e Mínimo

Tags: javascript

Estou com dificuldades com um código em JavaScript. Seguinte:

Escreva uma função `maxmin(a, b, c, d, e)` que receba cinco números como parâmetros.
Sua função deve retornar um array onde o primeiro elemento é o menor dos parâmetros da função `maxmin` e o segundo elemento é o maior dos parâmetros da função `maxmin`.

O que eu fiz:

```js
function maxmin(a, b, c, d, e) {
  var menor = Math.min(maxmin())
  var maior = Math.max(maxmin())
  console.log(menor, maior)
}
maxmin(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você criou um loop infinito quando a função chama a si própria – na verdade, criou dois, porque você fez isso duas vezes. O que você deve passar para as funções nativas (`Math.min`, `Math.max`) são os parâmetros `a, b, c, d, e`. Portanto:

```js
function maxmin(a, b, c, d, e) {
  var menor = Math.min(a, b, c, d, e)
  var maior = Math.max(a, b, c, d, e)
  return [menor, maior];
}
console.log(maxmin(2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Resolvi!